# Certain iOS users experience crash when filtering Algolia results

Tags: swift, algolia

The Algolia search api returns an object like this:

```
"hits": [
{
  "foo": {...},
  "bar": {...},
  "objectID": {...},
  "_highlightResult": {...},
  "downloads": {...}
}]
```

And I want to list the keys so that only "foo" and "bar" remain.

```
keyArray = Array(chosenObject!.keys)
// returns ["downloads", "_highlightResult", "objectID", "foo", "bar"]
keyArray = keyArray.filter{$0 != "objectID"}
keyArray = keyArray.filter{$0 != "_highlightResult"} //Crash here
keyArray = keyArray.filter{$0 != "downloads"}
```

When I do this, it works for me and for most of my users. But about 2-3% of my users experience a crash when filtering out "_highlightResult". It doesn't matter where that line is in the order, it will always happen when filtering out "_highlightResult" and I've been messing with it for days.

They're almost all running iOS 11.3 or 11.2 on iPhones.

EDIT: To clarify, "Foo" and "Bar" can be different words. ObjectID, downloads, and _highlightResult are always returned, but "foo" and "bar" can be called different values, which is why I'm looking for their names.

Answer (score 1):

As your issue is not triggered systematically, I believe it's because the _highlightResult array is either empty or null, depending on the search. As I'm only a JS developer, I'm not sure how it applies in mobile, but I know that I always process highlight and snippet attributes after testing their value.

Answer (score 0):

Your crash may be due to force unwrapping here `keyArray = Array(chosenObject!.keys)`. Instead of this do like this:

```
if let keyArray = Array(chosenObject.keys) {
   let newList = keyArray.filter{ $0 == "foo" || $0 == "bar" }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, but to clarify "foo" and "bar" may be different words - the other three (downloads, objectID, and _highlightResult) are returned with every result, but I'm trying to find the remaining two values after those have been removed